# Regex to Split by comma and remove text delimiters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need a regex to split a sting by **comma** but also remove the **double quotes** of the text field delimiters.

Sample string:

> "Test1", "Test2", 3, 4, "Test5"

Required List

> - Test1
> - Test2
> - 3
> - 4
> - Test5

Thanks
JP

Comment: Hi Kobi.
The answer you quoted does not split by a comma and also remove double quotes from the resultant list!
JP

Comment: Your "required list" has no double quotes, either (and I'd argue you don't actually need double quotes anyway), but you should look at the second answer in the other thread. *That's* the one you really want to use.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!